# How to get rid of subtle white pixel border on Eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

How can i get rid of white pixels borders on Eevee?
These are just appearing on the preview and render image.
The imported image sequence does not have these little white pixels on it.
If i move the threshold parameter (third image) it works like a fix, **but what is the correct way to import/export the image to skip these white pixels?**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does changing the clip threshold have any effect?

Comment: yes! it kinda worked, but still feels like a 'patch', what i want is a direct solution to this.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you using openEXR instead of png. go on your image texture node and try to change linear to closest or to cubic

Then try putting color ramp in between and choose constant interpolation.

btw if you want to make a cirlce procedurally, here is the tree:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, if i conver the openEXR to png later, would it still have the same information on it? because i need to later import my render to another software.

Comment: EXR stores more information than png, so you would still retain the image information. Also this format is used in other softwares so it may be supported there too